# Visual Studio: class wizard malfunctioning

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2005

Several class wizard functions aren't working, most of which I don't need very badly, but not being able to add classes to MFC controls is a big problem. I have an MFC dialog project going on, and whenever I try to, say, add a function to a class I just get "The operation could not be completed"--not very helpful. If in the resource view I right-click on a dialog and select "Add Class..." nothing happens.

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 w/SP1. I'm running WinXPHESP3 32-bit.

BTW, this project was imported from VS 6.0, so I've got a bunch of things lying around like `AFX_MSG_MAP`, which I'm starting to suspect is useless and maybe interfering.

Comment: First, VS2005 is pretty old.  Second, have you tried to "repair" visual studio?

Comment: @rrirower Yeah, well, XP is pretty old, too.

No, I haven't tried a repair. How would I go about doing that? My next step was going to be to ask how to clear out any cache files and whatnot, that a project clean wouldn't.

Comment: Try to set up a new project, copy all your files into there, see if that makes a difference. You need AFX_MSG_MAP markers to let VS know where it can insert its code. You could try to remove it, and see if it gets added back when VS can't find it. I doubt that'd fix your issue though.

Comment: Re-run visual studio install. There should be an option to repair or modify the install.

Comment: Close your project, delete *.ncb and *.aps and reload it (it will recreate them). These have been a notorious cause of the older wizards failing.

Comment: There is no [MFC Class Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748520.aspx) in Visual Studio 2002/2003/2005/2008. Are you talking about the [MFC Add Class Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ayf8605.aspx) instead? If so, please update your question to make this clear.

Comment: @rrirower Repairing just got me a lot of errors about installing individual files and nothing was fixed. I uninstalled and reinstalled and I got fewer of those errors, but the wizard works again.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in comments, a repair didn't work, so I did a reinstall. That also had a few errors, but VS seems to work now. If I had to do it all over again, I might have tried reinstalling the SP1 first.